# Cannot read property of 'undefined', on last item in array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I can keep adding or removing records from my array and it will work fine until it gets to the last one, even if the record is an exact copy of one it has already worked on.

Array:

```
[
{
    "adID": "1",
    "isDefault": "false",
    "adName": "Ad 1 Name",
    "adDesc": "Ad 1 Description",
    "adURL": "",
    "adFormat": "image",
    "adImages": {
        "adImageDSK": "../img/bgfour.jpg",
        "adImageDEV": "../img/bgfour.jpg"
    }
},
{
    "adID": "2",
    "isDefault": "true",
    "adName": "Ad 2 Name",
    "adDesc": "Ad 2 Description",
    "adURL": "",
    "adFormat": "image",
    "adImages": {
        "adImageDSK": "../img/bgnine.jpg",
        "adImageDEV": "../img/bgnine.jpg"
    }
},
{
    "adID": "3",
    "isDefault": "false",
    "adName": "Ad 3 Name",
    "adDesc": "Ad 3 Description",
    "adURL": "",
    "adFormat": "image",
    "adImages": {
        "adImageDSK": "../img/bgseven.jpg",
        "adImageDEV": "../img/bgseven.jpg"
    }
},
{
    "adID": "4",
    "isDefault": "false",
    "adName": "Ad 4 Name",
    "adDesc": "Ad 4 Description",
    "adURL": "",
    "adFormat": "image",
    "adImages": {
        "adImageDSK": "../img/bgfive.jpg",
        "adImageDEV": "../img/bgfive.jpg"
    }
}
]
```

jQuery:

```
$.getJSON("../json/adverts.json", function (data) {
    "use strict";

    function loadAdData() {
        adArray = [];
        $.map(data, function (item) {
            adArray.push({
                'isDefault': item.isDefault,
                'adID': item.adID,
                'adName': item.adName,
                'adDesc': item.adDesc,
                'adURL': item.adURL,
                'adFormat': item.adFormat,
                'adImageDSK': item.adImages.adImageDSK,
                'adImageDEV': item.adImages.adImageDEV
            });
        });
    }

    loadAdData();

    var defArray = adArray;
    console.log(defArray);
    var newArray = [];

    $.each(defArray, function (i, item) {
        if (item.isDefault === 'true') {
            newArray.push({
                'adID': item.adID,
                'adName': item.adName,
                'adDesc': item.adDesc,
                'adURL': item.adURL,
                'adFormat': item.adFormat,
                'adImageDSK': item.adImageDSK,
                'adImageDEV': item.adImageDEV
            });
            defArray.splice($.inArray([i], defArray), 1);
        } else {
            console.log(item.adID);
        }
    })
}
```

The real array is 10 items long, but they are copy and pastes of the above with the numbers changed. I'm pulling some adverts from a file and checking to see if any of them are 'defaults' that have to show, put them in a different array for use later on.

Comment: Which exactly row produces the error?

Comment: Why do you use splice ? I think problem is about splice()

Comment: Ah yes I wasn't clear on that.  The console log for item.adID is showing me it is pulling the data in, and the fact that the one item that isDefault = true doesn't show it's ID in the console.  It then shows me the next couple after that so thats not causing it to stop either, the splice is fine.  When it starts the last record in my JSON file it errors out and tells me it cant find property of undefined.  This happens if I have 2 or 20 records in.  It fails on the last one, even if it has previously not failed on the record when it wasnt the last one.

Comment: It shows the error on the line if (item.isDefault === 'true') { but only on the last record, regardless of how many records I remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply want to [filter](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Array.prototype.filter) the array.

```
function Advert(data) {
    this.isDefault = data.isDefault;
    this.adID = data.adID;
    this.adName = data.adName;
    this.adDesc = data.adDesc;
    this.adURL = data.adURL;
    this.adFormat = data.adFormat;
    this.adImageDSK = data.adImages ? data.adImages.adImageDSK : null;
    this.adImageDEV = data.adImages ? data.adImages.adImageDEV : null;
}

$.getJSON("../json/adverts.json").done(function (data) {
    var allAds = data.map(function (item) {
        return new Advert(item);
    });
    var defaultAds = allAds.filter(function (ad) {
        return ad.isDefault === 'true';
    });

    // ...
});
```

Comment: Took me a few minutes to work out how this was doing what it does but yeah this achieves almost the desired result.  I can copy the defaultAds code and rename it optionalAds and return if false to get two arrays with them separated out and then go from there.  Thanks!

Comment: You can also build 2 separate arrays right from the start with an each instead of a map, if that's what you want.